# BeautifulSoup find text through 2 terms in html tag - Python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape some text from a html file however i need 2 types of text which differ from each other by a term (`contextref`) in their tags, for example:

1) `<ix:nonfraction contextref="cfwd_30_04_2016" name="ns5:TangibleFixedAssets" unitref="GBP" decimals="0" format="ixt2:numdotdecimal" scale="0" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">180,649</ix:nonfraction>`

2) `<ix:nonfraction contextref="cfwd_30_04_2015" name="ns5:TangibleFixedAssets" unitref="GBP" decimals="0" format="ixt2:numdotdecimal" scale="0" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">200,395</ix:nonfraction>`

at the moment my code to find the text is : `var1=(soup.find('ix:nonfraction',{'name':'uk-gaap:{}'.format(variable)}).text)` which for the examples above give: 180,649.

For me to be able to get both values i would need another variable to include another term along with `name`, (being `contextref`) ive played around with different combinations but cant seem to make it work.

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: is this xml code ? and post the output you want.

Comment: nope, the files are all `.html`

the ideal output would be for `var1` to include the text file from the first tag = 180,649 and `var2` to be from the second = 200,395.

might be worth noting that the two tags aren't under the same head tag

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4

html = '''<ix:nonfraction contextref="cfwd_30_04_2016" name="ns5:TangibleFixedAssets" unitref="GBP" decimals="0" format="ixt2:numdotdecimal" scale="0" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">180,649</ix:nonfraction>
<ix:nonfraction contextref="cfwd_30_04_2015" name="ns5:TangibleFixedAssets" unitref="GBP" decimals="0" format="ixt2:numdotdecimal" scale="0" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL">200,395</ix:nonfraction>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
var1, var2 = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('ix:nonfraction')]
```

out:

```
('180,649', '200,395')
```

you can use `contextref` as key word in `find_all()`:

```
soup.find_all('ix:nonfraction', contextref=True)
```

This means filter the tag which has `contextref` attribute.

Comment: because the html doesnt just contain that tag, there are loads of tags with contextref as a result im getting: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 58, in <module>
    var1, var2 = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('ix:nonfraction')]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

ideally i would need a code to look for the specific `ix`, `name`, and `contextref`